# Великий комбинатор. Задача на комбинаторику. Python

Tags: python, комбинаторика, олимпиада

Дана задача, [условие и проверяющая система](https://acmp.ru/index.asp?main=task&id_task=158), условие также продублирую здесь:
В результате очередной хитроумной комбинации у Остапа Бендера и его компаньонов - K детей лейтенанта Шмидта оказалось X рублей пятирублевыми банкнотами. И вот дело, как водится, дошло до дележа...

Шура Балаганов предложил "по справедливости", т.е. всем поровну. Паниковский порешил себе отдать половину, а остальным "по заслугам". Каждый из K детей лейтенанта предложил что-нибудь интересное. Однако, у Великого Комбинатора имелось свое мнение на этот счет...

Ваша же задача состоит в нахождении количества способов разделить имеющиеся деньги между всеми участниками этих славных событий: K детьми лейтенанта Шмидта и Остапом Бендером.

Входные данные

Во входном файле INPUT.TXT записаны целые числа X (0 ≤ X ≤ 500) и K (0 ≤ K ≤ 100). Естественно, что число X делится на 5. Да и при дележе рвать пятирублевые банкноты не разрешается.

Выходные данные

В выходной файл OUTPUT.TXT выведите одно целое число - количество способов дележа.

Задача решена, и притом должна быть верно. Решение задачи - C^K(Y+K)

Обычно пишу на плюсах, решил обойти длинную арифметику с помощью python здесь, дабы сэкономить время, и на первом же тесте с Д.А. задача валится, хотя я проверял вывод (я проверял также на ideone.com), и длинные числа выводятся корректно, как мне кажется, можете пожалуйста помочь найти и устранить ошибку в коде? Спасибо

Мой код:

```
import math
x, k = input().split()
x = int(x)
k = int(k)
y = x // 5
print(int(math.factorial(y + k) / (math.factorial(y) * math.factorial(k))))
```

Comment: Вы не забыли, что участников дележа - (К+1)?

Comment: @Akina нет, в этом плане решение верное, да и к тому же первые 8 тестов моя программа проходит, а 9(там, где начинается длинная арифметика) валит тесты

Comment: *где начинается длинная арифметика* Для начала уберите `int` в операторе `print` - результат не может быть НЕ целым...

Comment: @Akina мне нужно выводить целое число, а иначе оно выводится в формате {число}.0, поэтому добавил int.
UPD если убрать int - валит первый тест

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При вычислении количества сочетаний промежуточные результаты могут быть слишком велики. Однако можно избежать вычисления слишком больших факториалов, сократив одинаковые члены в числителе и знаменателе.

Более того, можно ещё уменьшить промежуточные результаты за счет того, что при обходе множителей числителя по убыванию, а знаменателя - по возрастанию, мы можем постоянно сокращать текущее значение на очередной член знаменателя.

```
def cnk(n, k):
    k = min(k, n - k)
    if k <= 0:
        return 1 if k == 0 else 0
    res = 1
    for i in range(k):
        res = res * (n - i) // (i + 1)
    return res
```

Answer (score 0):

Используй библиотеку scipy.

```
import scipy.special
scipy.special.comb(10, 5, exact=True)
```

Если `exact=True`, то вычисляться будет точное целое значение.

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.comb.html#scipy.special.comb

Comment: Нет ничего идеального.  А вместо ссылки лучше написать полноценный ответ. Ссылка может умереть  и Ваш ответ будет безполезен.

Comment: Спасибо, вот так лучше?

Answer (score 0):

Немного подправил ваш код (заменил `/` на `//` и убрал `int()`) и решение прошло:

```
import math
x, k = input().split()
x = int(x)
k = int(k)
y = x // 5
print(math.factorial(y + k) // (math.factorial(y) * math.factorial(k)))
```

**Объяснение (на примере CPython):**

- `//` возвращает `int`. Тип `int` поддерживает числа любого размера - внутри число хранится в Сишном массиве, разделённое на 30-ти битные кусочки.
- `/` возвращает `float`. Питоновский тип `float` внутри хранит значение в виде [double](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8) - базовом Сишном типе.

Поэтому, при

```
y = 100
k = 500
```

**Целочисленное деление:**

```
>>> factorial(y + k) // (factorial(y) * factorial(k))
111141121906618545240953242952818541227345601115424676450872121134189914598140023602766426232743669077626371495249376
```

Просходит деление одного "длинного" числа на другое с остатком, частное возвращается в виде `int` типа.

**Обычное деление:**

```
>>> factorial(y + k) / (factorial(y) * factorial(k))
1.1114112190661855e+116
```

Просходит деление одно "длинного" числа на другое без остатка, [частное переводится](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/7dc72b8d4f2c9d1eed20f314fd6425eab66cbc89/Objects/longobject.c#L4079) в Сишный `double`, соответственно результат из точного превращается в приближённый.